# In Propel2, filter crossref by null value

Tags: php, orm, propel

I use Propel2 orm.

I've 2 tables Entry and Category connected by a many-to-many relationship via an EntryCategory table.

I set isCrossRef on true in schema.xml.

Everything works fine : I'm able to filter entry by category like this :

```php
EntryQuery::create()->filterByCategory($cat)
```

BUT

I'm not able to filter entries **with no category**. I tried

```php
EntryQuery::create()->filterByCategory(null, Criteria::EQUAL)
```

or

```php
EntryQuery::create()->filterByCategory(null, Criteria::ISNULL)
```

but, it gives me

```
'filterByCategory() only accepts arguments of type \Category or Collection'
```

I also tried

```php
EntryQuery::create()->where('Category IS NULL')
```

but, i've got this error

```
Unknown column 'Category' in 'where clause'
```

So, I need some help ...

EDIT :

Extract of my schema.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<database package="core" name="bank" identifierQuoting="true" defaultIdMethod="native" defaultPhpNamingMethod="underscore">
  <table name="category" idMethod="native" phpName="Category">
    <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" size="5" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="name" phpName="Name" type="VARCHAR" size="50" required="true"/>
    <column name="parent_id" phpName="ParentId" type="INTEGER" size="5"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="category" phpName="Parent">
      <reference local="parent_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <index name="parent_id">
      <index-column name="parent_id" size="5"/>
    </index>
    <vendor type="mysql">
      <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
    </vendor>
  </table>
  <table name="entry" idMethod="native" phpName="Entry">
    <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="account_id" phpName="AccountId" type="INTEGER" required="true"/>
    <column name="date" phpName="Date" type="DATE" required="true"/>
    <column name="entry" phpName="Entry" type="VARCHAR" size="255" required="true"/>
    <column name="type" phpName="Type" type="INTEGER" size="2"/>
    <column name="amount" phpName="Amount" type="DECIMAL" size="12" scale="2" required="true"/>
    <index name="account">
      <index-column name="account_id"/>
    </index>
    <index name="md5">
      <index-column name="md5" size="32"/>
    </index>
    <index name="md5_2">
      <index-column name="md5" size="32"/>
      <index-column name="account_id"/>
    </index>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="account">
      <reference local="account_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <vendor type="mysql">
      <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
    </vendor>
  </table>
  <table name="entry_category" idMethod="native" phpName="EntryCategory" isCrossRef="true">
    <column name="entry_id" phpName="EntryId" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="category_id" phpName="CategoryId" type="INTEGER" size="5" primaryKey="true" required="true"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="entry" name="entry_category_ibfk_1">
      <reference local="entry_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="category" name="entry_category_ibfk_2">
      <reference local="category_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <index name="category_id">
      <index-column name="category_id" size="5"/>
    </index>
    <vendor type="mysql">
      <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
    </vendor>
  </table>
</database>
```

Comment: Try `->where('Entry.CategoryId IS NULL')`

Comment: or `->filterByCategoryId(null, Criteria::ISNULL)`

Comment: Thanks, but I've got the following error :  `Unknown column 'Entry.CategoryId' in 'where clause'` for your first proposition, and `Unknown column CategoryId in model Entry` for your second one.

Comment: well, then you should better post your schema.xml, otherwise we can't wild  guess your columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Id or Name or whatever the column name is.

`->filterByCategory` expects a propel object of the category type.
`->filterByCategoryId()` or whatever the name for the actual column is. (having your schema would be beneficial)

Not passing anything sets it up to look for null. Anything else is handled as a string literal.  `where column = 'null'`

---

Use either `->filterByCategory()` (if that is the name of your column and NOT a foreign key reference) or `->filterByCategoryId()` if 'CategoryId' is the 'phpName' of the column.

Comment: Thanks, but when I use of `crossRef=true` in schema.xml only the objects filter is created (in this case `->filterByCategory`). I don't have the `->filterByCategoryId`.

Comment: My second problem is related to the type of the join of the `crossRef=true` : It's an `INNER JOIN`. I need `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found 2 solutions (yes, 5 years after ;) )

```
EntryQuery::create()->leftJoinCategory->where('Category.CategoryId IS NULL')
```

Or

```
EntryQuery::create()->useCategoryQuery(null, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN)->filterByCategoryId(null, Criteria::ISNOTNULL)->endUse();
```